# Not able to delele task from Account

Tags: trigger

I am not able to delete task from Account. I am getting below error on page

Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s).

> The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger TaskTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: TaskTrigger: execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: ()".

Click here to return to the previous page.

Comment: Can we see your TaskTrigger?

Answer (score 0):

Code in a trigger is preventing the record from being saved. If you're the developer, you need to find and identify the code causing the issue and fix it. Otherwise you need to alert your developer.